# Приставка и суффикс

Tags: суффиксы, приставка

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли?

Образуй от данных слов однокоренные слова с суффиксом или приставкой.
Читать, играть, ходить, строить.

Читать — корень «чит», суффикс «-ать», окончание нулевое (о.н.);
Прочитать — корень «чит», приставка «про-», суффикс «-ать», о.н.;

Играть — корень «игр», суфф. «-ать».
Выиграть — прист. «вы-».

Ходить — корень «ход», «-ить»
Переход — «пере-»
Переходный — «пере-», «-н», окончание «-ый»

Строить — корень «стр», суфф. «-оить»
Строительный?

Answer (score 1):

Читать — корень «чит», суффикс -а-, окончание/суфф. -ть;Посмотрите, как в Вашем учебнике разбирается -ть-как суфф. инфинитива или окончание? В разных научных школах по-разному.

Про/чит/а/ть — корень -чит-, приставка про-, суффикс -а-, оконч./суфф.-ть.;

Игр/а/ть . Вы/игр/а/ть .

Ход/и/ть  Пере/ход/нулев. оконч. Пере/ход/н/ый

Стро/и/ть Стро/и/тель/н/ый

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в слове «рисовать» один суффикс «-ова-» или два: «-ов-» и «-а-»?

Comment: -ова- Это в прилагательных может быть суфф -ов-, а в глаголах -ова/-ева-

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!